# Android Studio Flavour of a Flavour

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently using Android Studio to build a app and I have multiple flavours such as the following:

```
build1 {
        applicationId "com.build1"
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2.0"
    }

build2 {
        applicationId "com.build2"
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1.0"
    }
```

I am looking to include a new build, `build3`, that is identical to `build2` in every way except it will have one extra pop up when the app opens. I understand how to set up a new flavour but How do you expand one flavour to include another? I am looking to share the code base of `build3` with `build2` and then add the slight extra code needed. Is there a way that you can do this using gradle or will I have to copy all of the code used in `build2` into the `build3` directory?

EDIT:
`build1` and `build2` share common code in the `main` folder but also have some separate code, string, colours, layouts etc. I am looking to let `build3` build from `build2` and gain access to its own resources.

Comment: you can check `if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("build3")) { showThePopup(); }` in the code ... or add `buildConfigField "boolean", "SHOULD_BE_POPUP", false` (false in build2 and true in build3) in the flavour and then check in the code `if(BuildConfig.SHOULD_BE_POPUP){ showThePopup(); }` ... in this way both, build2 and build3 could use the same code ...

Comment: @Selvin I did consider that but the issue i am having is that while `build1` and `build2` share some code, they also have code, strings, colours etc that are separate from each other. How would i tell `build3` to follow the `build2` while also adding extra code?