# Multiple orthogonal axes of Android flavours

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors

I currently use flavours to customise an app for each customer.

I've read: [Android Studio Flavour of a Flavour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900612/android-studio-flavour-of-a-flavour)

I now need to *also* customise the app for different user roles.

These customisations are orthogonal, the app needs to be buildable for all customer/role combinations.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Could more than one flavour be applied - like mixins?

(Making a flavour per customer/role combination would be very wasteful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flavour Dimensions look like a good answer:

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants